# Knockout maping.fromJS for observableArray from json object. Data gets lost

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping

I have a view model with an observable and an observableArray. A button click is suppose to populate a JSON object and map it to the view model...which I believe "should" populate the observableArray. The button click happens. No errors. If I run through the debugger when the mapping occurs the obserable object gets populated but the obserableArray does not. Which means that the HTML objects that are suppose to display based on the observableArray do not get updated.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="if: ErrorMessages().length"> <span>Error Messages</span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ErrorMessages">
        <li> <span data-bind="text: Description"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: ShowErrors">Go</button>

var ViewModel = function () {
    var me = this;
    me.AData = ko.observable();
    me.ErrorMessages = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Javascript:

```
    me.ShowErrors = function () {


        var testdata = {
            AData: {
                Something: 1
            },
            ErrorMessages: [{
                Description: 'Error #1',
                Code: '01'
            }, {
                Description: 'Error #2',
                Code: '02'
            }]
        };
        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(testdata);

        ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, me);
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Eves/v9SEk/4/

My real code reaches out and gets data from a web service. I figure the above creating an object and converting it to JSON and then mapping it using ko.mapping.fromJS best represents what is happening. Anyways...

I suspect I've done something stupid, or at least, assumed something I should not have.

Comment: ko.mapping.js is not found in your external resources, which is why THAT isn't working

Comment: knockout.mapping.js is in the jsfiddle "External Resources". Is that not the right one?

Comment: LOL...what a horrible copy and paste job I did. External resources should be fixed now. However, the problem still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting to JSON with `ko.toJSON(testdata)` but you are not reading from JSON with the 
`ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, me);` but from a plain JS object.

The `toJSON` and `fromJSON` method should be used in pairs:

```
var jsonData = ko.toJSON(testdata);

ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonData, {}, me);
```

and the same applies to the `toJS` and `fromJS`:

```
var jsonData = ko.toJS(testdata);

ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, {}, me);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jR4k/).

Comment: Yep, that fixes the jsfiddle. Thanks. Now I just have to apply that to the nonsense that is my real code.